# Why is it difficult to propagate intransitive relations over a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, semi-supervised-learning

In the paper [Semi-Supervised Learning by Mixed Label Propagation](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2007/AAAI07-103.pdf), they say

> One major limitation with most graph-based approaches is that they are
> unable to explore dissimilarity or negative similarity. This is
> because the dissimilar relation is not transitive, and therefore is
> **difficult to be propagated**.

Why is it so?